# How to show complete files that changed in git log

Tags: git, git-log

How to I show unabbriviated files that changed in gitlog? Right now the files are cut to only show one or two lines before and after deleted lines of code. I would like to show the whole file of each change.

My current command that I run is `git log -w --full-history --date=local -p --format="%H"` How can I run a command that does not abbreviate the changed files?

```
7d45603c29d0b7e451424cb5b181e6af16485a4f

diff --git a/ui/src/org/pentaho/di/ui/spoon/ExpandedContentManager.java b/ui/src/org/pentaho/di/ui/spoon/ExpandedContentManager.java
index 3c41b27..84db90a 100644
--- a/ui/src/org/pentaho/di/ui/spoon/ExpandedContentManager.java
+++ b/ui/src/org/pentaho/di/ui/spoon/ExpandedContentManager.java
@@ -33,6 +33,7 @@ import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener;
 import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
 import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
 import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
+import org.pentaho.di.core.Const;
 import org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph;

 import java.util.function.Consumer;
@@ -160,6 +161,9 @@ public final class ExpandedContentManager {
     if ( !isVisible( graph ) ) {
       maximizeExpandedContent( browser );
     }
+    if ( Const.isOSX() && graph.isExecutionResultsPaneVisible() ) {
+      graph.extraViewComposite.setVisible( false );
+    }
     browser.moveAbove( null );
     browser.getParent().layout( true );
     browser.getParent().redraw();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git diff --no-prefix -U1000` where `-U1000` is 1000 lines of code which you can change to your preference